# Accessing rows of a numpy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

I am confused with how to access rows of a numpy ndarray. I have an array like the following:

```
X
print(X.shape)
(100,1,1)
```

Now when I try to access its elements the following happens:

```
X[0]
print(X[0].shape)
(1,1)
```

I also tried:

```
print(X[0,:].shape)
(1,1)
```

I was expecting get something with a shape like `(1,1,1)`. Am I missing something or is it just supposed to be like this?

Comment: Every time you access an index, you loose a dimension. So it's perfectly normal.

Comment: @JulienBernu Could you please explain why? I could not find anything regarding this. Also, what if I want the shape of it to be `(1,1,1)` ? Should I just reshape it?

Comment: That's just the definition: a 2d array is an array of 1d rows, if you pick the ith row you get a 1d row.  Yes reshape it.

Comment: Try `x[[0],:]` or `x[0:1,:]`. That is make the index a list or slice.